# Nested route with a fixed component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In the below routing:

```
const Main = props => (
  <main className=''>
    <Account {...props.account}></Account>
    <Route path="/tab1" component={Tab1}/>
    <Route path="/tab2" component={Tab2}/>
  </main>
);

const App = (props) => {
  const state = props.store.getState();
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <section >
        <Route path="/main" render={() => (<Main account={state.account} />)} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

        <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
        <Link to='/main/tab1'>Tab1</Link>
        <Link to='/main/tab2'>Tab2</Link>
      </section>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I want to have the `Account` component above other components (tabs). Tabs will load based on their route but `Account` is always there, except in `/login` page.

But what I get is:

- In `/login` I get the `Login` as expected.
- In `/main/tab1` and `/main/tab2` I only get `Account` and tab components don't render.

May questions are:

- What I'm doing wrong?
- Is there a way I can write this without defining `Main` component?

Thank you

Comment: @trixn I used it solely because their parent is pointed to `/main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes in the  component point to `/tab1` and `/tab2` but your url is `/main/tab1` or `/main/tab2`. You have to prefix them with `/main`. This doesn't happen automatically. One way would be to pass your match object to your `Main` component and prefix your `path` with a template string, this is better than hardcoding it in case you change your url to the `Main` component:

```
const Main = props => (
  <main className=''>
    <Account {...props.account}></Account>
    <Route path={`${props.match.url}/tab1`} component={Tab1}/>
    <Route path={`${props.match.url}/tab2`} component={Tab2}/>
  </main>
);

const App = (props) => {
  const state = props.store.getState();
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <section >
        <Route path="/main" render={({match}) => (<Main match={match} account={state.account} />)} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

        <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
        <Link to='/main/tab1'>Tab1</Link>
        <Link to='/main/tab2'>Tab2</Link>
      </section>
    </Router>
  );
};
```